# Is UEFI more or less vulnerable than Legacy BIOS?

Tags: windows, security, bios, malware, uefi

Is UEFI more secure than BIOS on a Windows 8.1 machine?

Is UEFI vulnerable to malware in ways that Legacy BIOS is not?

Is it correct that UEFI can connect to the internet before the OS (or anti-virus program) has loaded? 
On some boards, UEFI settings can be changed in Windows.
Do these things affect PC security?

I have read that BIOS on an MBR disc can be vulnerable to 'rootkits'
There have been reports that suggest UEFI secure boot may not be infallible.
Is UEFI better at defending against malware than BIOS?

Answer (score 3):

First, note that malware affects the OS, not the BIOS itself (because there is no value in controlling a BIOS). if someone is attempting to attack the BIOS, their real goal is to attack the OS that that BIOS will boot. Rootkits and other boot time exploits are designed to attack the OS by affecting how it gets booted.

Traditionally BIOS and firmware code is not terribly susceptible to malware, and with few notable exceptions, the security of the BIOS is not particularly important when Malware is the vector for attack. BIOS security measures are primarily for the purpose of restricting physical accesses that may allow an attacker to bypass software imposed limitations (for instance booting to a live CD to bypass file system permissions).

BIOS code is not in itself vulnerable to malcode, but it is a point where an attacker could leverage exploits such that the software security measures are ineffective. 
The primary place where the BIOS CAN help with software security, is the boot loader process, and this is what most people are talking about when discussing [UEFI's more advanced security features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824987.aspx). UEFI allows OEMs and advanced users to set up cryptographic certificates that work with the boot loader so that only approved OS's may be booted, and to ensure that they have not been modified improperly by malware. if an attacker can alter the code of the OS's boot loader (perhaps by wrapping the bootloader in its own malicious code), they can bypass a great deal of the operating systems underlying security (like its ability to process cryptographic keys for validating drivers). [Rootkits and other MBR exploits are more easily prevented using these features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dn168167.aspx). You are correct UEFI is not foolproof; remember **physical access == root access. Period.**

BIOS settings can be modified by the OS via the [APCI (Advanced power Configuration Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) but because there are very few settings available that impact software security,this would have little impact. That the UEFI system can access the internet on its own is not necessarily an issue, unless an exploit against the embedded browser is discovered. Normal windows exploits will not work, and will have to be specially crafted for this particular use case to be effective.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That said, new exploits are always being discovered and no software is immune. It's best to not make assumptions about something being "perfectly secure" when diagnosing attack vectors.

Comment: The BIOS/UEFI es a valid target because if malware is installed here it can affect the user, perform malicious activity and affect the OS. I also disagree with the affirmation that the UEFI is able to access Internet is not an issue...it is another place where malware can connect to the Internet and it has an important impact in security. Moreover this answer do not respond to the question of security benefits of UEFI.